# How long it takes an investment to double within a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I’m supposed to find how long it takes a given investment to double at an annualized interest rate(The rate will be an input). The investment can be any given figure though. (I'm supposed to use While Loops and its Python btw).

For my program, this is what I did:

```py
def Invest():

    rate = int(input("Enter the annualized interest rate: "))

    year = 0
    principal = 1

    while principal != (principal*2):
        interest = (principal * rate * 1)/100
        principal = principal + interest
        year += 1
    print("The number of years it takes for your investment to double is",year)

Invest()
```

Well, it works, but even though I use 50 as my rate, I get a really large number of years. I feel as if I'm supposed to add something but I don't know what exactly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start from fixing this strange condition: `principal != (principal*2)`.

Comment: Ok, that was helpful, I worked around it and I found out that the problem was trying to find the exact double of the value. I made it: principal < (principal*2)  . Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem is in while condition principal != (principal*2), that's why you are getting a large number of years

Answer (score 0):

```
r = float(input("Enter the annualized interest rate: "))
def interest(r):

    
    year = 1
    principal = 10
    bound=principal*2
    while principal <= bound:
        principal=(principal+r/100)+1
        year=year+1
        print(principal,year)

interest(r)
```